# Postgres documentation in GNU Info format

Tags: postgresql, emacs, docbook, info

**Postgres** is an open-source project and it has *DocBook* as default format for its documentation. At a first glance it looks like a tree of *.sgml files in the [doc directory](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/doc) inside a repository.

There are several pre-defined convertion output formats, but unfortunately *Emacs' native* one is ignored.

Does it possible to get Postgres documentation as a *postgres.info.gz* file?

Answer (score 2):

That's basically nothing more than a text conversion problem. I believe the *right* solution here would be to write an XSL that converts the XML in your SGML files to TeXinfo source code, but the next best thing:

`pandoc` is a parser for different textual document file formats. It has a reader for Docbook and a writer for texinfo. That should get you started.